# Как обновить данные на странице во flask-socketIO

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, websocket, socket.io

У меня имеется код:

```py
@app.route('/brutality/api/matchmaking/start/', methods=['post', 'get'])
def API_Matchmaking():
    accountDates = LobbyFiender.User(
        session['login'], session['password'], session['nick'])
    if LobbyFiender.Lobby.GetOpensLobby(accountDates.lvl) == 0:
        accountDates = LobbyFiender.User(
            session['login'], session['password'], session['nick'])
        lobby = LobbyFiender.Lobby.CreateLobby('def', f"{accountDates.lvl}")
        LobbyFiender.save()

        try:
            return f"{lobby.pCount}"
        except:
            return f"1"

    elif LobbyFiender.Lobby.GetOpensLobby(accountDates.lvl) >= 1:

        accountDates = LobbyFiender.User(
            session['login'], session['password'], session['nick'])
        lobby = LobbyFiender.Lobby()
        lobby.SearchGameRequest(accountDates.lvl, accountDates.name)
        if lobby.pCount == 9:
            lobby.AddPlayersToLobby(accountDates.name)
            LobbyFiender.save()
            return redirect("/gamedata/")
        else:
            lobby.AddPlayersToLobby(accountDates.name)
            LobbyFiender.save()

            print(lobby.pCount)
            return f"{lobby.pCount}"

    else:
        return "False"


@si.on("get_data")
def handle_update_data(data):
    lobby = LobbyFiender.Lobby()
    data = lobby.id

    # Отправка данных всем подключенным клиентам
    emit('data', data, broadcast=True)


@si.on("connect")
def handle_connect():
    print("Socket connected!")


@app.route("/gamedata/")
def redirectGameData():
    lobby = LobbyFiender.Lobby()
    return render_template("/mm/gamedata.html", lobby=lobby)
```

мне необходимо что-бы у всех пользователей обновлялись данные на странице после каждого захода на страницу любого пользователя, но который час у меня ничего не выходит, прошу подробно объяснить как это сделать

Comment: Не уверен что в этом проблема, но есть разные функции во flask-socketIO — `si.emit()` и `emit()`. Одна контекстно зависимая, другая нет, следовательно поведение у этих функций разное.

Comment: не помогло, поставил si.emit везде где надо было